# How to update table within a date and time range?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that has columns Date, Time, a, b and c. Date is a date data type, time is a time data type and a, b and c are float.

I need to add a constant value to entries in column b for a given date and time range, but not for all values.

I can create a `SELECT` query that gets me the data I want to update, but I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to figure out how to update the original table.

The working SELECT query is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP(`Date`, `Time`) `DateTime`, `b` FROM `my_db`.`my_table`
) as selectdata
WHERE `DateTime` > "2015-02-06" AND `DateTime` < "2015-08-01 10:45:00"
```

Is there a way that I update the entries in column `b` and then write the new values over the original values in my_table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TIMESTAMP()` expression in the `WHERE` clause for the `UPDATE`:

```
update my_db.my_table
    set b = b + CONSTANT
    where TIMESTAMP(`Date`, `Time`) > '2015-02-06' and
          TIMESTAMP(`Date`, `Time`) < '2015-08-01 10:45:00';
```

Comment: Thank you; that worked perfectly. One minor correction: set b = b + CONSTANT.